# Issue with jersey in Android Application

Tags: android, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to use jersey client in Android Application, but I am getting this error.

```
05-26 07:18:47.442: W/System.err(1934): com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 07:18:47.442: W/System.err(1934):     at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
05-26 07:18:47.442: W/System.err(1934):     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
05-26 07:18:47.452: W/System.err(1934):     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
05-26 07:18:47.452: W/System.err(1934):     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
05-26 07:18:47.452: W/System.err(1934):     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
```

Code that I am using is :

```
String devEmail = "test123@gmail.com";
String apiKey = "a975d70e-bebc-4270-8160-d71fa5241bd2"; 
String pkgName = "com.test";
String appId = "com.testtestApp";
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource webResource =  client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:4444/webbService/apiCheckTest").build());
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("devEmail", devEmail);
formData.add("apiKey", apiKey);
formData.add("pkgName", pkgName);
formData.add("appId", appId);

ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
System.out.println("Response " + response.getEntity(String.class));
```

Please help me to find the issue. I am unable to debug.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
WebResource webResource =  client.resource("http://localhost:4444/webbService/apiCheckTest");
```

instead of

```
WebResource webResource =  client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:4444/webbService/apiCheckTest").build());
```